# Run local external python script in terminal from Vue application

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, server

hi I am a beginner to vue js and firebase. I am building a simple GUI for a network intrusion detection system using vue js. I have written a python script that allowed me to push the output from terminal to firebase. I am currently running the app in local host:8080

However in my vue app I want to run the local python script in terminal when I press the start button and kill the process when I press stop.

> I read online that doing it require a server. Does anyone have a good
>   recommendation on how I can do it?
>
> I hear that it may also be easier to just use 'child_process' from
>   node js but I can't use it in vue js.

What is the best / simplest way to implement it.

```
<template>
  <div id="new-packet">
    <h3>Start/Stop Analysis</h3>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Start</button>
    <router-link to="/home" class="btn green">Stop</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'new-packet',
  data () {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Its not in the scope of vue - you need a jitter scope that is capable of  running python  scripts - node, electron , custom v8 implementation

Comment: thus would you suggest using node or electron or others? because its just a simple button

Comment: If it is a desktop gui  use elektron (node), in vue ui  just add electron  plugin and use child -process or  some python  lib

Answer (score 2):

You can use FLASK/DJANGO to setup restFul API for your python function as suggested by @mustafa but if you don't want to setup those frameworks then you can setup simple http server handler as -

```
# This class contains methods to handle our requests to different URIs in the app
class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    # Check the URI of the request to serve the proper content.
    def do_GET(self):
        if "URLToTriggerGetRequestHandler" in self.path:
            # If URI contains URLToTriggerGetRequestHandler, execute the python script that corresponds to it and get that data
            # whatever we send to "respond" as an argument will be sent back to client
            content = pythonScriptMethod()
            self.respond(content) # we can retrieve response within this scope and then pass info to self.respond
        else:
            super(MyHandler, self).do_GET() #serves the static src file by default

    def handle_http(self, data):
        self.send_response(200)
        # set the data type for the response header. In this case it will be json.
        # setting these headers is important for the browser to know what   to do with
        # the response. Browsers can be very picky this way.
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        return bytes(data, 'UTF-8')

     # store response for delivery back to client. This is good to do so
     # the user has a way of knowing what the server's response was.
    def respond(self, data):
        response = self.handle_http(data)
        self.wfile.write(response)

# This is the main method that will fire off the server. 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print(time.asctime(), 'Server Starts - %s:%s' % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER))
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print(time.asctime(), 'Server Stops - %s:%s' % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER))
```

and then you can make call to the server from vue using AXIOS as -

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('/URLToTriggerGetRequestHandler')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

**I don't think there is anyway you can directly call a python script from js or vue.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to install django or flask in local machine. Do a restful api like her https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api

- Write your python inside
- Call python code from vue js by using restful url.